# Selecting row values which contains a specific list values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as:

```
df1      df2    df3
Dell.    10.  [intiated, purchased]
Apple    20.  [initiated]
Toshiba. 15.  [purchased]
```

I would like to filter row values base on the values from df3.

Example filtering for df3 when value is [intiated, purchased] should return

```
df1      df2    df3
Dell.    10.  [intiated, purchased]
```

Example filtering for df3 when value is [intiated] should return

```
df1      df2    df3
Apple.    20.  [intiated]
```

Example filtering for df3 when value is [purchased] should return

```
df1      df2    df3
Toshiba.    15.  [purchased]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way:

```
val=['intiated','purchased']
#the value that you want to find
m=df['df3'].map(lambda x:all(y in val for y in x))
#check the value 'val' is inside your list or not(it will give you boolean series)
```

Finally filter out result by passing `m`:

```
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

output of above code:

```
    df1     df2     df3
0   Dell    10  [intiated, purchased]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC here's one way:

```
df['df3'] = df['df3'].astype(str) # convert to string type if required
req_val =  '[initiated]'
filtered_df = df[df['df3'].eq(req_val)] # use boolean indexing to filter
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
     df1   df2          df3
1  Apple  20.0  [initiated]
```

Complete example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'df1': {0: 'Dell.', 1: 'Apple', 2: 'Toshiba.'},
 'df2': {0: 10.0, 1: 20.0, 2: 15.0},
 'df3': {0: '[intiated, purchased]', 1: '[initiated]', 2: '[purchased]'}})
req_val =  '[initiated]'
filtered_df = df[df['df3'].eq(req_val)]
```

Comment: It returns an empty dataframe.

Comment: @StackUser. added complete example for you